# Swift: Declaration in generic class

Tags: swift, generics

Let's say I have a generic class:

```
class SomeClass<Element> {
  // What is the difference between this:
  var array: [SomeClass]!

  // and this declaration:
  var array2: [SomeClass<Element>]!
}
```

What is the difference between those declarations?

Comment: It seems to be they are absolutely the same, only for `array` the generic argument is inferred. I can't find it in the language reference though.

Comment: Looks like there is none - I would have expected a difference but it seems like they are equivalent.

Comment: Note that you can alt-click on the properties in Xcode to see what it's inferring the type to be – indeed they appear to be the same. Seems to be a special case of type inference when referring to a generic class within its own declaration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A generic type cannot exist without its generic argument, therefore omitting the generic type means that you want the compiler to infer the type.

In this case the logical type to be inferred is `Element`.

Note that this works only because you have used `SomeClass` inside `SomeClass` declaration. It wouldn't work for a different generic class.

A similar inferring of generic arguments can be used in variable declarations:

```
let instance: SomeClass = SomeClass<Int>()
let array: Array = [1] // Array<Int>
```