# How to concatenate two dictionaries with a += operator overload

Tags: swift, dictionary, operator-overloading

I would like to concatenate two dictionaries with a += operator overload using the method below.

```
static func += <Key, Value> ( left: inout [Key : Value], right: [Key : Value]) {
    for (key, value) in right {
        left.updateValue(value, forKey: key)
    }
}
```

OR

```
static func +=<Key, Value>( left: inout Dictionary<Key ,Value>, right: Dictionary<Key, Value>) {
    for (key, value) in right {
        left.updateValue(value, forKey: key)
    }
}
```

With this implementation:

```
var properties = ["Key": "Value"]
var newProperties = ["NewKey": "NewValue"]
properties += newProperties
```

I get below error from xCode,

> Cannot convert value of type '[String: Any]' to expected argument type
>   'inout [_ : *]' (aka 'inout'Dictionary<*, _>)

It doesn't work, can anyone can help me or if it's not possible, explain me why?

Comment: Note that your code *as posted above* compiles without problems. It is always a good idea to create a new project with a [mcve] in order to avoid unclear problem statements.

Comment: @MartinR Technically it won't compile at the top-level with the functions being declared as `static`, but yeah – OP, please always provide an MCVE. Usually I hold off answering MCVE-less questions, but didn't think the extension assumption was too big a leap in this case (also spooky timing as always Martin :) ).

Comment: @Hamish: You are right, I forgot that I had removed the "static".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're defining this overload in a `Dictionary` extension, don't introduce `Key` and `Value` generic placeholders; use the generic placeholders already defined by `Dictionary` (as the ones you introduce yourself are completely unrelated to them):

```
extension Dictionary {

    static func += (left: inout [Key: Value], right: [Key: Value]) {
        for (key, value) in right {
            left[key] = value
        }
    }
}

var properties = ["Key": "Value"]
let newProperties = ["NewKey": "NewValue"]
properties += newProperties
print(properties) // ["NewKey": "NewValue", "Key": "Value"]
```

And you could also [let Swift infer this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37862276/2976878) by just taking `Dictionary` operands:

```
extension Dictionary {

    static func += (left: inout Dictionary, right: Dictionary) {
        for (key, value) in right {
            left[key] = value
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

#### Swift 4 alternatives

Since Swift 4 is around the corner, I'll add an answer (addressing, specifically, the question or the title) including additional approaches available upon its release.

The evolution proposal

- [SE-0165: Dictionary & Set Enhancements](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0165-dict.md#1-merging-initializers-and-methods)

is implemented in Swift 4, and will allow you to use methods such as the mutating [`merge(_:uniquingKeysWith:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2892855-merge) (or the non-mutating [`merging(_:uniquingKeysWith:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2892849-merging)) to combine two dictionaries, which also allows you to specify how to resolve key collisions.

E.g., implementing your `+=` function using `merge(_:uniquingKeysWith:)`, overwriting existing key-values (upon collisions) with the associated value in the right hand side dictionary:

```
extension Dictionary {

    static func += (lhs: inout Dictionary, rhs: Dictionary) {
        lhs.merge(rhs) { (_, new) in new }
    }
}

/* example usage */
var dictA = ["one":   1,
             "two":   2,
             "three": 3]

let dictB = ["three": 42,
             "four":  4]

dictA += dictB
print(dictA)
   // ["one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 42, "four": 4]
   // (any order is coincidental)
```