# Unable to Initialize a Generic type with a Generic method parameter

Tags: swift, generics, initialization

I was fiddling around with generic types in the Swift playgrounds, when I attempted to use the code below:

```
class Node<T> {
    let value: T

    init(_ t: T) {
        self.value = t
    }

    func convert<U>(to type: U.Type) -> Node<U>? {
        guard let new = value as? U else {
            return nil
        }
        return Node(new)
    }
}
```

**Note:** This code is hypothetical and is not meant to do anything in the real world.

On line 12, where I return the new `Node` from `Node.convert(_:)`, I get this error message:

```
U' is not convertible to 'T'
```

Now this seems rather odd to me. In theory, since we can create a `Node` with any type, shouldn't we be able to use any generic type initialize it? Does this have something to do with the type inference not being able to infer the type?

Comment: Just because you can create a Node with any type doesn't mean that Nodes created with a different type are the same.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth They aren't supposed to be the same. The second node is supposed be a different type.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/37862276/2976878 – you need to say `Node<U>(new)`

Comment: No in your convert function you are specifically asking for a return type of Node<U>? and therefore you must return that type and not Node<T>?  So as @Hamish has said use Node<U>(new).  If you try Node<T>(new) instead you will find you are told that T is not convertible to U.