# Swift Array() coercion ambiguous without more context — but only in extension

Tags: arrays, swift

It is legal to say this (`arr` is an Array):

```
let arrenum = Array(arr.enumerated())
```

So why isn't it legal to say this?

```
extension Array {
    func f() {
        let arrenum = Array(self.enumerated())
        // error: type of expression is ambiguous without more context
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT** It seems this is a workaround:

```
extension Array {
    func f() {
        typealias Tup = (offset:Index, element:Element)
        let arrenum = Array<Tup>(self.enumerated())
    }
}
```

But why is that needed? (And is it right?)

Comment: Could it be related to the type inference of `Array` into `Array<Element>` when dealing with member functions?

Comment: That's [a known bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1789) – Swift eagerly assumes that the generic placeholders for any reference to a generic type within its own body (including in an extension) is the same as `self` (so in this case Swift is trying to do `Array<Element>(self.enumerated())`, which fails). See https://stackoverflow.com/q/37862276/2976878 for a similar issue.

Comment: @Hamish you should post your comment as an answer, since you're conclusively answering the question. I figured it was something along those lines.

Comment: @DuncanC Sure thing, will do in a sec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known bug ([SR-1789](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1789)). Swift currently has a feature where you can refer to a generic type within its own body without having to repeat its placeholder type(s) – the compiler will infer them for you to be the same as the type of `self`.

For example:

```
struct S<T> {
  func foo(_ other: S) { // parameter inferred to be `S<T>`.
    let x = S() // `x` inferred to be `S<T>`.
  }
}

extension S {
  func bar(_ other: S) {} // same in extensions too.
}
```

This is pretty convenient, but the bug you're running into is the fact that Swift will *always* make this inference, even if it's incorrect.

So, in your example:

```
extension Array {
    func f() {
        let arrenum = Array(self.enumerated())
        // error: type of expression is ambiguous without more context
    }
}
```

Swift interprets the code as `let arrenum = Array<Element>(self.enumerated())`, as you're in the body of `Array<Element>`. This is incorrect, because `enumerated()` yields a sequence of offset-element tuple pairs – Swift should have inferred `Array` to be `Array<(offset: Int, element: Element)>` instead.

One workaround, which you've already discovered, is to explicitly specify the placeholder type in order to prevent the compiler from making this incorrect inference.

```
extension Array {
  func f() {
    let arrenum = Array<(offset: Int, element: Element)>(self.enumerated())
  }
}
```

Another possible workaround appears to be using the fully-qualified type, for example:

```
extension Array {
  func f() {
    let arrenum = Swift.Array(self.enumerated())
  }
}
```

as it appears Swift doesn't do the same inference for fully-qualified types (I'm not sure if you should rely on this fact though).

Finally it's worth noting that instead of doing a call to `Array`'s initialiser, you could use `map(_:)` instead to avoid the issue entirely:

```
extension Array {
  func f() {
    let arrenum = self.enumerated().map { $0 }
  }
}
```

which, like the initialiser call, will give you back an array of offset-element pairs.