# Why may a generic type not use a concrete version of itself?

Tags: swift, generics

#### TL;DR

- Why may we not use a concrete version of a generic type within its own generic implementation? Since it's a concrete type, I see no issues with "recursive typing". Is this a design decision? Or a current limitation?

---

**Background**

When playing around with generics, I stumbled over the following (for me, previously unknown) curiosity:

```
struct Foo<T> { let foo: T }

struct Bar<U> {
    let bar: U

    func foobar() -> Foo<Bar> {
                   /* ^^^ Bar<U> inferred */
        // no matter of the actual implementation ...
        return Foo(foo: self)
    }

    // even without inference help from the implemention
    func nilFoobar() -> Foo<Bar>? { return nil }
}
```

Particularly how the return type of `foobar()` needn't specify the placeholder type of `Bar` (which in turn is the placeholder for the generic `Foo` return), as this seems to be inferred as the same placeholder type as `Self` (concrete `U` in `Self`). I.e., as I see it, the above is equivalent to (except for the Option-click description of the `foo()` method in Xcode)

```
struct Foo<T> { let foo: T }

struct Bar<U> {
    let bar: U

    func foobar() -> Foo<Bar<U>> {
        return Foo(foo: self)
    }

    func nilFoobar() -> Foo<Bar<U>>? { return nil }
}
```

Since `Bar` in the return type of `foobar()` is inferred<sup>†</sup> as `Bar<U>`, I realized that this in turn should disallow a generic types using concrete versions of itself (something I've never had or have a reason to do ...). As expected, this theory holds:

```
struct Foo<T> { let foo: T }

struct Bar<U> {
    let bar: U

    func foobar() -> Foo<Bar<Int>> {
        return Foo(foo: Bar(bar: 1))
                              /* ^ error: 'Int' is not convertible to 'U' */
    }

    // concrete version of other generic type naturally allowed
    func fooint() -> Foo<Int> {
        return Foo(foo: 1)
    }
}
```

<sub>[†] Rather than inferred, perhaps a shortcut for is a better description? Since it compiles even without an actual implementation to fall back to w.r.t. inference.</sub>

**Question**

I don't have any use for using concrete versions of `Self` within a generic type, but with some imagination, I could see this being used in some corner case context. More so, out of a technical viewpoint (and curiosity), I'm interested in why this seems to be disallowed by design.

- Why may we not use a concrete version of a generic type within its own implementation? Since it's a concrete type, I see no issues with "recursive typing". Is this a design decision? A current limitation?

I hope this question doesn't fall under opinion-based. Given the open official community of Swift, maybe someone can shed official-connecting light for the reasoning as to why this should be disallowed by design (or is it simply a current "limitation"?).

Comment: Related: [What is the cause of this type error?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37862276/2976878) – [Swift: Declaration in generic class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37765714/2976878)

Comment: You just have to specify the generic placeholder if it's something other than the placeholder used for the 'outer type', e.g `return Foo(foo: Bar<Int>(bar: 1))`. The compiler is just a little dumb in this situation w.r.t completely ignoring the fact that you're passing a `1` into `Bar`'s initialiser as well as the explicit type annotation of the method return.

Comment: @Hamish I can only say, "doh"! I even tried `return Foo(foo: Bar(bar: Int(1)))` but no cookie :) Thanks! I actually stumbled over the first case (the non-demand that we specify the typeholder of `Bar` in `foobar()` return when when within in `Bar`) when looking at your nice Collection implementations, [this line in particular](https://github.com/hamishknight/Swift-Collections/blob/master/Swift%20Collections/CollectionOfTwo.swift#L47): `<Element>` is not needed in the return type of the subscript declaration (but I guess it's nice to have for semantics).

Comment: Oh I've actually removed the `<Element>` locally haha! But yeah, like I said, in your case the compiler's being pretty dumb :) There's actually a bug report for it: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1789

Comment: @Hamish yeah I thought I knew most of the cases-of-stupidity of the compiler by now (hence my total lack of trying to return an explicitly typed `Bar<Int>`), but alas, another new case for me! Thanks, add an answer (and preferably the bug report) if you want.

Comment: Hmmm, just wondering whether it would be better to post a new answer or close as dupe of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37862276/2976878), as I don't think I'll be saying too much more than I said there – thoughts?

Comment: @Hamish Yeah, that's probably appropriate. That answer in its current form doesn't mention the bug report though (Jordan:s comment to the bug report you linked explains it pretty well: the eager feature becomes a mess-up in special cases such as the one in this thread). I suggest either closing it as a dupe directly; or, first adding a short answer here, highlighting your insights in these comments (as well as a link to the bug report), whereafter we dupe-close this one it to target (so they're linked, as they are indeed covering the same issue). Re: thoughts? :)

Comment: I can always just edit my answer to include the bug report w/ Jordan's comments – I *think* that would be preferable over having two answers (although I've changed my mind about 5 times already trying to decide).

Comment: @Hamish my own too-much-time-spent-on-a-single-question dupe-hammered by myself, somewhat a semi-fail!

Comment: Haha :) I've gone ahead and edited my answer with the bug report.