# Generic dictionary extension error - ambiguous reference to subscript

Tags: swift, generics

I'm playing with generics in Swift 3 (Xcode 8.2.1) and I don't understand why this won't compile. I also tried `self.updateValue`... and that fails also.

```
extension Dictionary {
    mutating func mergeWith<K: Hashable, V: AnyObject> (a: [K:V]) -> [K:V] {
        for (k,v) in a {
            self[k] = v // compile error: Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to limit the types of generics K and V to what works with a Dictionary, but that doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a particularly helpful error, but the problem is that you're introducing *new* local generic placeholders `K` and `V` in your method – which need not be related in *any way* to the `Dictionary`'s `Key` and `Value` types (remember that generic placeholders are satisfied by the *caller*, not the callee).

So just simply remove them and use the existing generic placeholders `Key` and `Value` instead, i.e take a `[Key : Value]` parameter. Or better still, take advantage of the fact that Swift [automatically infers the generic placeholders](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37765714/2976878) of a generic type when you refer to it inside of itself, and just type the parameter as `Dictionary` (which will resolve to `Dictionary<Key, Value>`).

```
extension Dictionary {
    mutating func merge(with dict: Dictionary) {
        for (key, value) in dict {
            self[key] = value
        }
    }
}
```

Also `mutating` methods usually don't return the mutated instance, so I removed the return type from your method.

Comment: Thanks. I sure wish the error messages were in any way indicative of why the error was occurring, rather than the last part of some stack...

Comment: @xaphod Yeah, unfortunately there still are lots of cases where the diagnostic messages from the compiler are far from satisfactory. Although to be fair on the Swift team, the situation is generally getting better. It can be worth [filing a bug report](https://bugs.swift.org) when you encounter lousy error/warning messages – they do generally get taken notice of.