# Methods of parameterized types can omit type parameters

Tags: swift, generics

I read the following suggestion on https://github.com/github/swift-style-guide/blob/master/README.md

But this part i don't understand. what receiving type is and what receiver is?
thanks.

> #### Omit type parameters where possible
>
> Methods of parameterized types can omit type parameters on the
>   receiving type when they’re identical to the receiver’s. For example:
>
> ```
> struct Composite<T> {
>   …
>   func compose(other: Composite<T>) -> Composite<T> {
>       return Composite<T>(self, other)
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> could be rendered as:
>
> ```
> struct Composite<T> {
>   …
>   func compose(other: Composite) -> Composite {
>       return Composite(self, other)
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Compare [Swift: Declaration in generic class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37765714/2976878) & [What is the cause of this type error?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37862276/2976878) – the type of `Composite` in the scope of `Composite<T>` is inferred to be `Composite<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

“Type parameter” refers to the concrete type of the generic structure. For example you could have a struct `A` of type `Composite<Int>`. The type parameter is `Int`. A type parameter like `T` is a generic type parameter that can stand in for any sort of concrete type, unless constrained.

The style guide is using the fact that the Swift compiler is very good at inferring the type parameters, so you can just write `Composite` without the type parameters. You can do this if, in this example, the initializer for `Composite` specifies that both arguments must be of the same type. Since Swift knows that `self` is of type `Composite<T>`, then it knows that `other` must also be of type `Composite<T>`, and since `Composite.init(::)` returns a struct of the same type, then the return type is `Composite<T>`. This of course, all depends on the initializer.

Personally, I disagree with the style guide on this point. Always better to be explicit, the angle brackets don’t take up that much space.