# Where do I need to give Swift generics placeholder's type? And where it's not necessary?

Tags: swift, generics

For the code below, I **don't** get any compiler errors indicating that the you need to specify the generic type of `Node` (for leftChild & rightChild)

```
class Node<T: Comparable>{

    var leftChild: Node? // WHY NO ERRORS?!
    var rightChild: Node? // WHY NO ERRORS?

    var value: T

    init(value: T){
        self.value = value
    }

    func addleft(node: Node){
        leftChild = node
    }

    func addright(node: Node){
        rightChild = node
    }
}
```

However for the struct below I get an error if I don't specify the generic type.

```
struct LinkedList{
   var head: Node? // ERROR!
}
```

> error: reference to generic type 'Node' requires arguments in <...>

This is understandable. I know I need to do something like:

```
struct LinkedList<T:Comparable>{
    var head: Node<T> // NO Error!
}
```

So why doesn't the `leftChild: Node?` line throw any errors?! How does it know its generic type? Why isn't it necessary to write as such?

```
var leftChild: Node<T>?
var rightChild: Node<T>?
```

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/37765714/2976878

Comment: @Hamish The funny thing is, I never thought about this until Honey's question. I guessed rightly that we must be inferring the resolution of the placeholder, but I waited for you to come along and tell us. :) I almost don't like this feature; maybe you should have to say `Self` or something.

Comment: @matt no matter how minute it feels good to be able to finally be able to give back to omega users like you :). Didn't get what you mean by _maybe you should have to say ‍`Self‍‍‍` or something_ Can you explain?

Comment: I don't like when Swift is too "clever", leaving mysteries like the one you noticed. If `leftChild:Node` means `Node<T>` by default, I feel you should have to _say_ `Node<T>` to make that fact explicit. The `Self` type might cover it instead; `Node<T>` is a specific type.

Comment: @matt Personally I like the feature, though I do appreciate how it can be seen as not particularly obvious (especially given I don't *believe* it's officially documented). Though once we get [universal `Self`](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0068-universal-self.md) (which I hope will cover this use case), I agree that would be a nicer way to spell it (and then I'd be happy for the "generic type referred to within itself inference" feature to go).

Comment: Wow, reading that (https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0068-universal-self.md) was really confusing. I wish they'd put dates on these things, and maybe go back and notate them when things have changed!